# Asynchronous call into a Synchronous call in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, synchronous

In essence I am going to make a call to a remote XMLRPC server and it will process the request asynchronously.

```
import xmlrpclib

client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8080')

client.add(3,5)


def add_result(result):
    print result
```

I know at some point in the future that add_result will get called with the result. The thing is. I want to be able to turn the call client.add into a blocking call that will return the result. I'm doing this for a GUI that will be calling on me. The question is where should I be looking to read about this sort of solution? I'm not really sure where to start.

I don't think I've explained myself well at all.
The server I am calling is implementing the aynchronous part. When I call add it will return true. And I know that the server is expecting me to implement add_result which is what it will call on me. What I am trying to do is clean this crazy scheme up so that someone can call add on me and I will block until add_result is called on me, I will then return to whoever called me. I hope this clears things up

Comment: Huh? Thats not how xmlrpclib works, the call `client.add(3,5)` blocks and returns something like any other function. Do you mean twisted's xmlrpclib ?

Comment: What magickery did you think exist to make `add_result` act like a deferred callback and `client.add` to be asynchronously called?

Comment: Sorry, I've explained myself badly, hope the edit clears it up

Comment: Still no idea what you're trying to do...even post edit.  Are you saying you want to call `client.add()` and have a callback function fire off when it finishes?

Comment: Hi Kev,(I don't think I'm doing well at this) I'm not saying I want to. I'm saying that the server I'm calling (which I have no control over) is going to callback onto me after it has performed some function. What I want to do is tie those two things together

Answer (score 0):

Your claim is nonsense. xmlrpclib operations are synchronous and blocking. For performing asynchrous operations etc. you need to implement something using threads.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with pynator...

But in case you need help on the blocking piece...the design to block is pretty simple:

```
class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.blocking_thread = Thread(target=self.get_data)
        self.client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(...)

    def  query_for_data():
         self.blocking_thread.start()
         self.blocking_thread.join()

    def get_data(self):
        while(True):
            #this assumes this returns some how and doesn't block..
            result = self.client.add(...)
            if(result): break;

            time.sleep(1)
```